# Multiple Log4J Bindings Error

Tags: logging

In my application, I get the following WARN messages:

```
[info] Resolving jline#jline;2.12.1 ...
[info] Done updating.
[info] Running com.test.KafkaConsumerBoot 
SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/Users/joe/.ivy2/cache/org.slf4j/slf4j-log4j12/jars/slf4j-log4j12-1.6.1.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/Users/joe/.ivy2/cache/ch.qos.logback/logback-classic/jars/logback-classic-1.1.1.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
SLF4J: Actual binding is of type [org.slf4j.impl.Log4jLoggerFactory]
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (akka.event.slf4j.Slf4jLogger).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.
```

I understand that there is somewhere some duplicate logging library being used, but which one is it? I have the following defined as my application dependencies:

```
  object Libraries {
    val typesafeCfg  = "com.typesafe"      %  "config"     % Versions.typesafeConfig
    val playJson     = "com.typesafe.play" %% "play-json"  % Versions.playJson
    val playHttp     = "com.typesafe.play" %% "play-ws"    % Versions.playHttp

    // spray http server libraries
    val sprayRouting = "io.spray" %%  "spray-routing" % Versions.sprayVersion
    val sprayHttp    = "io.spray" %%  "spray-can"     % Versions.sprayVersion

    val monifu       = "org.monifu"        %% "monifu"    % Versions.monifu
    val kafka        = "org.apache.kafka"  %% "kafka"     % Versions.kafka
    val jodaTime     = "joda-time"         %  "joda-time" % Versions.jodaTime

    val log4j        = "log4j"             %  "log4j"  % Versions.log4j
    val scalaLogging = "com.typesafe.scala-logging" %% "scala-logging" % Versions.scalaLogging
    val slf4J        = "org.slf4j" % "slf4j-api" % Versions.slf4J

    val scalaTest    = "org.scalatest" %% "scalatest" % Versions.scalaTest % "test"
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is:

```
"org.apache.kafka" % "kafka-streams" % kafkaVersion exclude("log4j", "log4j") exclude("org.slf4j","slf4j-log4j12"),
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.